# PHP Mailer Script for sending Unlimited Mails

Tags: php

I am facing a problem with sending bulk emails to all my recipients (approx 10,000) It sends about 600 - 800 mails and then just stops without any reason. I am using a shared server.

Here is My Code.

```
    <?php
@session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
    echo "<html><head>";
    echo "<script language=javascript>function load25(){
    alert('........................You Must Login .........................');
    window.location='email_login.html';}</script>";
    echo "</head><body onload=load25()></body></html>";
    die();
}

include "connection.php";

$uid=$_SESSION['uid'];

//var_dump($uid);

require_once('mail.message.php');
require_once('mail.info.php');

$email_id=uniqid();
$m="<html><body>";
$m.= $_POST['content'];
$subject= $_POST['subject'];
$m.="<img src='http://emailpro.in/mail/trackerimage.php?utm_source=gmail&utm_medium=email&utm_content=image&utm_campaign=services&campaignID=1&subscriberID=".$email_id."&subject=".$subject."'  border='0' alt='' style='height:1px;width:1px' />";


$to1=$_POST['to'];
$username=$_POST['usid'];
$passwd=$_POST['ppwd'];
$replymailid=$_POST['repmid'];
$campname=$_POST['campname'];
//echo" $replymailid <BR> $campname";

$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$date1= $date->format( 'y/m/d  H:i:s');
//echo $date1;
//$datetimee= date('y/m/d - H:i:s') ;
    //date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
//echo "Time Is $date ";
function nowhitespace($data)
{
    return preg_replace('/\s/', '',$data);
}
$to2=nowhitespace($to1);
$b=rtrim($to2,',');
//Print_r($b);

$s=array();
$s=explode(",","$b");
$n=$_POST['no'];

//echo "The number of emails u have selected is $n<br />";

$s=array();
$s=explode(",","$b");

$s1=implode(",", $s);



$Email = new Email();
$Email->sender = $replymailid;
   $Email->recipient=$s1;
$Email->subject =$subject;
$Email->message_text = "Hello!";
$Email->message_html = $m;
// send the email
$Courier = new Courier();
$sent = $Courier->send($Email);

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentmails VALUES('','$uid','$campname','$subject','$b','$n','$date1')");


/*if(isset($_POST['no'])!=" ")*/
if($n!="")
{
    $rec = mysql_query("SELECT * from clientmailid where userid='$uid' limit $n");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($rec);
   // echo $count;

    if($n!=0 && $count!=0 && $n<=$count)
    {
       // echo $n;
        $recipients = mysql_query("SELECT * from clientmailid where userid='$uid' limit $n");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recipients))
        {
            $addresses[]= $row['emailid'];
            //echo $addresses;
        }

        $to = implode(",", $addresses);
       // print_r($to);
       /*  $Tos=array();
        $Tos=explode(",","$to");
        $Tos1=implode(",", $Tos);
        */ $Email->recipient=$to;

    } else
 {
         echo '<html>';
         echo '<head></head>';
       echo '<body onload=load30()>';
        echo '</body>';
         echo'</html>';
        echo "**Sorry You Don't have enough Email Credits**";
    }
}

if ($sent != Courier::SEND_OK) {
  echo "Mailer Error" ;
}
else {
    if($n!=0 && $count!=0){
        $n=$_POST['no'];
        $recipients = mysql_query("SELECT * from clientmailid where userid='$uid' limit $n");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($recipients))
        {
            $addresses[]= $row['emailid'];
            $mid=$row['mid'];
            $result13 = mysql_query("delete FROM clientmailid where mid='$mid' limit $n");
            //echo $addresses;
        }

    }
    echo"<script>alert('Thank u for using emailpro Your mails will be processed and will be sent shortly');</script>";
    echo '<script>    window.location="./dashboard.php";</script>';
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function load30()
{
  alert("Sorry u don't have enough email credits");
  window.location='./tofill.php';
}


</script>
```

I know that we can send send unlimited mails through a shared server and I am sure there is something wrong either with my code or something with the server. Please guide me accordingly....

Thanks

Comment: Decompose your code, it is impossible to read there

Comment: I don't see a reason, why your question would be tagged with `css` or `html` or `jquery` tags

Comment: I think this is impossible to send unlimited mails for free, your server probably use a free service, you have to pay a service/firm who will send your massive mails

Comment: You posted 538 lines of code wit lots of included files, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you still want to send all email using PHP why not you just download [phpList](https://www.phplist.org/) .. it's free and you can install in your shared server!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, not because I can read it (please put clearer code on SO) but that it sends a random amount between 600-800 successfully. The following problems are most likely and one of them or both will solve the problem:

**1)** One of the potential reasons can be PHP timing out the script. Every script gets to run for a limited amount of time. If your script takes more time than that then PHP will simply kill the script. Typically that should cause an error being reported in the error logs. Check your apache error log messages - they might contain a hint.

Just add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in the top of your mailing script to test if this is the problem.

**2)** Could this be being caused by your local mail server? If you're sending out 10.000 emails in a short space of time, it might be assuming that it's spamming, and stop once you reach a certain amount. Try creating a mailing queue and sending in periodically.